# How do you specify an icCube permission to deny access to all members of a dimension but allows access to one?

Tags: iccube

I trying to set a permission for a user such that this user can only access a specific value of a dimension, other values are denied on this dimension.

Tried this but does not seem to work

```
:schema [Sales]
-tuples DC { [Countries].members}
+tuples DC { [Countries].[UK]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example authorizing the [France] member only. Please refer to the online [documentation](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/security/schemas_perms.php) for more details. Quoting this documentation:

*Permissions are defined using "lines"; each line is either granting access (+) or denying access (-) to the defined MDX entity(ies). Within a scope, the first '+' means all entities are DENIED first whereas the first '-' means all entities are AUTHORIZED first.*

So the following example is starting with a [+] within the [Sales] schema scope:

```
+schema [Sales]

:schema [Sales]

+tuples DC [Customers].[Geography].[Region].[Europe].[France]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Marc, do I have to restrict all levels and members on Europe first?